# Place amchart legend in a defined location

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

by below code part we simply create amChart (pie) on a defined div

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {.....

So it will find the div by id 'chartdiv' and create chart there. Is it possible and have anyone tried to set the div Id for the legend. So create div element anywhere we want in our page and legend render there, rather than position on top, or bottom or left or right.

Is it possible ? if so how ? :)

Comment: For some reason i found it. Thought to remove question, but in case if it is useful for someone ill keep it.
So answer is simple amcharts do have seperate legend =, so insted of using what is inside the existing chart you can simply create new legend and add that to chart. (https://plnkr.co/edit/0mtztpRwYpCeNzh0yBEk?p=preview)

var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
// chart is the chart i created earlier
 chart.addLegend(legend, "legenddiv");

Comment: found guidline provided by amCharts
https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/putting-a-legend-outside-the-chart-area/